# Make column auto incrementable with Laravel Migration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, database-migration

In laravel 5.2 is possible to modify a column to make it auto_increment? I have an ID column, its primary already, but it's not auto_increment, and I need to make it, how can I do it? I have registers in the table (each of them have the corresponding ID) so I cannot delete the registers.

Comment: You can always `DB::raw()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035836/how-to-add-auto-increment-to-an-existing-column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try the `change` method?

```
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id')->change();
});
```

See the documentation section on [changing columns](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#modifying-columns) for more info.

Comment: that is trying to add another id column, so it gives error

Comment: Updated my answer. What about with the `change` method?

Answer (score 0):

> Before modifying a column, be sure to add the doctrine/dbal dependency
>   to your composer.json file. Here is the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#modifying-columns)

```
 Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
    });
```

Comment: I tried this on Laravel 9 but it errors: "Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined" -- Note: if I don't add the `$table->bigIncrements('id');` but instead do `$table->unsignedBigInteger('id')->first()->primary();` it makes a non-auto-incrementing primary column. So the error is wrong, there are not multiple primary keys.