# Create new database table when user signs up for game items

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know a way to create a copy of a template database for each user when they register. Basically I have an items template database and when a user registers online, a table will be created like userItems that is a direct copy of the items table. I need to be able to do this in php or any way that can be done using a php register page. I was attempting to use CREATE TABLE x LIKE y command but for some reason this doesn't work, and it seems ineffective to then loop through y and put the contents into x.

Comment: Are you certain that this problem cannot be solved by creating a new record in a kind of meta-table? Creating a table per user that signs up is a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems to be the same problem like the author of this question had: [Duplicating a MySQL table, indexes and data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280006/duplicating-a-mysql-table-indexes-and-data)

(I'm missing the necessary reputation otherwise I would have commented the question)