# enumerate rows of a table into a new column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sequence

I have a table. I would like to select onto it a column that can serve as an index of sorts.

I have this table, `table1`:

```
col 1     col2  col3
a         b     c
d         e     f
g         h     i
```

I'd like to do:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1 AS
SELECT (some way to create a sequence from 1 to the height of the table) AS `seq`
,col1
,col2
,col3
FROM table1;
```

and get

```
seq    col 1     col2  col3
1      a         b     c
2      d         e     f
3      g         h     i
```

I've been googling around and can't seem to come across anything useful. Sorry, I'm also a beginner at MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a temp table, you can copy the table definition of `table1`, but add an autoincrement column.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1 (
  seq  INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  col1 VARCHAR(255),
  col2 VARCHAR(255),
  col3 VARCHAR(255)
) AS
  SELECT NULL seq
    ,col1
    ,col2
    ,col3
  FROM table1
;

SELECT * FROM temp1;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ea2e/1)

Comment: This is a great idea, I didn't think of it like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think these answers should help you:

Copy your table (except create as temporary) as from here:
[Duplicating a MySQL table, indexes and data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280006/duplicating-a-mysql-table-indexes-and-data)

Then write a procedure as described here:
[How can I loop through all rows of a table? (MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817395/how-can-i-loop-through-all-rows-of-a-table-mysql)

Comment: is this a 'link only answer'?