# Creating a LIVE copy of a dataset in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am building out a program/model based on a datatable hosted on my phpmyadmin (MySQL) account. This data table on phpmyadmin that is 100% critical to what we are doing, and even if it is the tiniest risk of something getting altered in here I cannot take it.

Thus the solution is to create a live copy of the dataset. So in theory I would have 2 identical data tables and one would be a copy (with an identifying suffix). We would only use the copy version, and routinely check if anything had been altered between the 2 tables.

I have created duplicates and copies of the data table, but cannot figure out how to create a live copy within phpmyadmin. I have created a live copy in google sheets, but I am working with a large dataset and would like to eliminate all intermediary, going straight from database to program.

Thank you for the help! Very much appreciated!

Comment: Is this what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280006/duplicating-a-mysql-table-indices-and-data

Comment: PhpMyAdmin is only a GUI, you can remove it and still use MySQL, those are unrelated tools. I guess you'd like to have recurrent copies ? If so, MySQL events could probably help you make copies once per day etc.

Comment: What do you mean "risk of getting altered"? **Use account permissions**. Don't hand out write access to anyone who doesn't need it.

Comment: What is the question? Are you trying to access MySQL from sheets perhaps? That is easy enough.