# MySQL insert failure records into another table

Tags: mysql, error-handling, database-migration

I'm doing db data migration in MySQL.

I have two tables - source (T1) & destination (T2).

I created one insert ignore script to migrate data from T1 to T2. during script run some record might have failed. So I want to capture these failed records in another table and publish the report out of it

Through a stored procedure I'm able to capture errors and inserted to error table.

But as I asked not use stored procedure so is there any alternative way to capture failure records and insert to error table

Thanks in advance

Comment: "But as I asked not use store procedure" ==> homework ?  What have you tried to solve this?  BTW: Why should any insert fail? Are those two tables not defined the same way ?

Comment: There can be data issue correct ,some invalid character .just defining table exactly means we won't get errors ?

Comment: You can always end up with errors like "disk full", so no one can guarantee that you will not get an error....

Comment: Exactly your correct, to capture such errors only need help.

Comment: Can you share more info, like why is this question different from [Duplicating a MySQL table, indices, and data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280006/duplicating-a-mysql-table-indices-and-data) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can log in to MySQL and specify your error log file:

```
mysql -u user -p 2> errors.log
```

Once you are logged in, run the commands that you have and all errors will be written into the file.