# Nextcloud oc_storages table has multiple "local::" entries -- how to proceed?

Tags: nextcloud

I have a Nextcloud instance that I've been running for several years, and I'm preparing to move a large collection of photos and videos into it (which I've been previously managing with rsync).  I came across [this howto](https://help.nextcloud.com/t/howto-change-move-data-directory-after-installation/17170) which gives relatively straightforward instructions that I feel comfortable with.

Before I started executing the steps in the howto, I took a look around to see if everything made sense.  While doing that, I discovered that my `oc_storages` table has multiple `local::` entries:

```
SELECT *
FROM oc_storages
WHERE id LIKE 'local::%';
```

[image: screenshot of database query results showing three rows with different paths]

The middle path (`local::/srv/nextcloud/data/`) is where Nextcloud currently resides on my system.  It has previously been at the other two locations at various points in the history of this server.  (Until today, I didn't realize that these paths were ever stored here!)

How do I clean up these old paths from the database?

I have not experienced any data loss when I moved my Nextcloud installation around in the past.  All of my files are currently visible in Nextcloud, and I've successfully synced (nearly) all of them to a new laptop a few months ago.  So Nextcloud definitely knows how to find the files on the disk.

Does this mean I can safely delete the two outdated rows from `oc_storages`, and all corresponding rows in `oc_filecache`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up taking some backups and trying it out for myself :)

Long story short, yes, you can delete the bad oc_filecache and oc_storages rows.

However, I *strongly* recommend taking a backup of the oc_filecahce and oc_storages tables before doing so (duplicating the table within the database, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3280006/8859073) demonstrates).  This way, if you break your Nextcloud instance, you can very easily copy over the rows you just deleted and try again.  (I had to do this a few times!)

I neglected to document the exact steps and order which I deleted the rows, but at the end of the day, I had no rows in oc_storages or oc_filecache which had the storage ID of those old rows.  There were additional other tables with file IDs on them that I checked.  At least one of them had file IDs that were missing from oc_filecache after I purged the bad rows, so I deleted the mismatched rows from that table as well.  I used `mysqldump --no-data` to dump the schema and ctrl+F for "file" in a text editor to find those tables.